# apt-get update hangs on fresh install of ubuntu 14.04.3 in virtual box

Tags: networking, virtualbox, ubuntu-14.04

OK, it has been a while since I have configured a virtual box from scratch.

1. Fresh install of ubuntu 14.0.4.3 lts
2. no proxy or anything fancy
3. the network adapter is set to bridged
4. after the os installed and booted I can

   a. ping the box from windows with success

   b. from within the box i can ping 8.8.8.8 with success (and other domains)

The problem is, I cannot get the box to run with success apt-get update. It just hangs at 0% which indicated to me that either the url it was access is not responding (gb.archive.ubuntu.com).. but it does respond in a browser, or the box could not make a connection to the www.. but then i can ping other domains.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Is there something I am missing? Why can I not get apt-get to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The screenshot shows APT resolves Ubuntu repository server to an IPv6 addresses. Have you checked your IPv6 connectivity (which can possibly be unavailable at all with your ISP)? The address you're using in diagnostics is IPv4, so this test may be irrelevant, try pinging some IPv6 addresses.

Check if it helps to add `ipv6.disable=1` to your kernel command line during boot. This can be made permanent with `dpkg-reconfigure grub...` - substitute the right GRUB package for your configuration.

Comment: Apologies for the delay :b  You were right, for some reason ubuntu on vmware cannot handle ipv6.  Adding "net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1" to "/etc/sysctl.conf"  and then a reboot solved the issue. muchos gracias!